# (Vue.js) How can I populate the select tag with option tag from array of number values in data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I would like to populate my select tag with options from an array variable which contains arrays of number values. But the values that are reproduced seems to be blank

HTML:

```
  <select required id="dropDown">
    <option>Select here</option>
    <option v-for="choice in choices">{{ choice }}</option>
  </select>
```

Javascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({   
el: 'body',    
data:{
    'choices': [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
});
```

Can someone point me of my mistake? Because I am just a beginner though, and I would like to learn from you guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `el` option should provide Vue with an existing DOM element to mount on. You have provided a CSS selector for body, so Vue will try to mount on the `body` element.

Otherwise your code is correct. Just wrap your HTML in `body` tags and it works!

```js
var vm = new Vue({   
  el: 'body',    
  data:{
    'choices': [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Load Vue JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>

<!-- add body tags so `el: 'body'` resolves to an HTML element -->
<body>
  <select required id="dropDown">
    <option>Select here</option>
    <option v-for="choice in choices">{{ choice }}</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get your data from the backend, you need to follow another way.
For example, I have a category list, which comes from the backend.

```
 <el-select
              v-model="categorySelect.selected"
              size="large"
              name="category_id"
              single
              v-bind:placeholder="$t('products.category')"
          >
            <el-option
                v-for="item in categorySelect.autocompleteItems"
                :key="item.id"
                :label="item.name_en"
                :value="item.id"
            ></el-option>
          </el-select>
```

Your script should looks like this :

```
categorySelect: {
    selected: [],
    autocompleteItems: this.categoriesItem,
  },

categoriesItem: {
      required: false,
      type: Object
    },
```

and then, you need to get your data on your view like this :

```
:categories-item="{{$categories}}"
```

as you see the above code, you can fill your select list with a different list that comes from the backend.

Enjoy Your Code!